# Pi4j image transmit to Android app

Tags: java, apache, android-studio

I want to take an image from raspberry and recive it on and Android App (this is the problem). I already have a Java project that create an image and store it in a predefined location.  I don't know how to create a server on Android app, and how to upload my image on the server. I think i will create a post webservice on raspberry to upload the image on my phone app.The image from rpi must be displayed on the phone (like notification or something). I need help on Android app, I don't know how to recive the image on the phone/how to send it from rpi location/how to show the notification when the image was send it/ how to show the image on the phone.

Comment: [This question is far too broad.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you say'd that is your urge